# Burned ST LINK by connecting it to the board

Tags: microcontroller, mains, stm32f4, jtag

I have a PCB that is getting powered from mains and is connected to a Hi Link component (HLK-5M05 with 5V output). At the moment it is connected to [an extensions with a button, a little bit like this one](https://www.findthetop10.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ISelector-1024x1024.jpg). When I power it on and start measuring I get the 5V output, 3v3 output, I can see that some components are working accordingly (voltage monitor) and then I went to load my firmware into the st microcontroller.

I disconnected eveything since I don't want to accidentally get shocked, I connect all the pins (gnd to gnd, 3v3 to Vapp, TMS -> TMS, etc). After I connected this I connected the board to the extension and turned on the button. Immediately I heard a loud noise and I noticed the st link wasn't ON anymore (a capacitor exploded) and the circuit breaker activated. Then I went to measure the board and I notice that there is a3v3 short to ground.

I have revised my entire layout and there is no connection between mains and GND in my circuit. The closest to it is the analog circuitry for measuring the voltage, but still, they are not connected. From what I can see everything is connected as it should be according to datasheets, but it still didn't work.

After that I tried connecting and programming my board via the bootloader. I did the required connections and tested my board and everything was working properly. Again I disconnected everything and connected the USB-serial board to my board (GND, TX and RX ... very simple and straight forward). When I connected everything the circuit breaker still activated but fortunately this time it didn't destroy my PCB.

Very distraught I turned off the button and went to disconnect the USB-serial board and got shocked. After that I measured the voltage between the USB connector and my PCB ground and there was 220Vac ... when the extension was turned off and the extension is not grounded (not USA .. incompatibility between different types of plugs ... old everything), but there is 0V when I measure the voltage between them when the extension is powered on.

What could I be doing wrong? I measured other devices (USB chargers and similar) and they all had the same behaviour ... 0V when ON and 220V when OFF. I have compared my schematic to others, such as open energy monitor and many other projects you can find online and I'm not doing anything crazy here (in terms of schematics and connections). Could there be something wrong with my installation? Or is it a PEBKAC (more like between PCB and chair [PEBPAC])?

**EDIT:**
Adding schematics, just the important part, the rest is all decoupling capacitors, oscillators, etc. 
[image]

Comment: Use a lab power supply when programming. And get an isolation transformer before you kill yourself.

Comment: And you're not going to get any useful advice from anyone until you post pictures and schematics.

Comment: Also, you could have a hot/neutral mix-up somewhere causing your plug strip to only interrupt the neutral connection.

Comment: You say the extension is not grounded. That means it has a reversible plug on it, right? When you plug it in there's a 50% chance that hot goes to neutral and neutral goes to hot. The switch will be in one of those wires but you don't know which. (I sure hope the extension has ungrounded sockets because otherwise that is a disaster waiting to happen when you plug in a grounded device!)

Comment: @alex.forencich Thank you for your advice, but I'm not afraid of death (just kidding .. very afraid (it's just difficult for me to get many tools), that's why I was disconnecting everything before even touching the board, the problem is that I got shocked when the extension was OFF ... and for some reason the JTAG got destroyed when I joined both GNDs)

Comment: @immibis I know ... the problem is that I can't really tell much about the socket and not even my own building ... but it probably isn't properly grounded (all the sockets I opened were, but I can't guarantee the building) .. also I just noticed that someone ripped the ground pin of my extension ... just recently my country changed the plug format and selling adapters is kinda illegal, so you have to either remove the pin or change the socket or buy a new device/make new cord (I can adapt from old to new but not from new to old .. with legal adapters)

Comment: @alex.forencich I borrowed a voltage detector and when turned off both pins were live. When turned off, only one was live

Comment: @immibis I borrowed a voltage detector and when turned off both pins were live. When turned off, only one was live

Comment: @morcillo that's because your switch is in the wire that the extension thinks is live, but which is actually the neutral because it's plugged in backwards.

Comment: @immibis Yeap ... after getting some sleep I just noticed that. First thing I tried today was to invert the connection and now there isn't 220V there, but there still is 2Vdc, and I can't use another jtag because the signals are 1V

Comment: @immibis I also forgot to mention that I hacked a 60V 10uF capacitor between N and 0V. My signal was pretty funky before the cap, and after the cap I get a nice sine wave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accidental mains-earth short. Don't we all make those one day.

1. You switched extension cord probably only switches **one line**.
   That way you do not know whether it switched Line of Neutral unless you explicitly measure it relative to mains earth.
   I'd recommend getting an isolator switch, an appropriate contactor, or just unplug.
   *Relays don't have enough distance and might get stuck on faults.*
2. Your circuit does have a path from mains to earth when you connect the programmer. But we don't know the impedance of this connection.
   Inside your PC the USB GND is connected to mains earth, and that's what has blown your ST Link.

[image]

The slightest current this way may upset power supplies. Or blow inputs if you do not connect ground first. Which is why typical connectors always connect ground first. eg: USB, HDMI, VGA, DVI, SATA, PCI. Except audio, which you've probably noticed one day will create a loud humm when not inserted correctly yet.

I'd recommend getting an **ST-LINK/V2-ISOL** if you plan to work with circuit like this further. But beware, your oscilloscope has the same problem! You can use a [differential probe](http://www.eevblog.com/product/hvp70/) with your scope.

Or buy an isolation transformer, that would remove the sparks on a fault. But can still result in strange behavior and shock hazards with a fault.

In the future, be aware of what potentials you connect.

---

In a comment you state that resistors r4, r5 and r6 are 200k and r7, r8, r9 are 820 Ohm. This means there was a short trough r7,r8 and r9 to earth.
I'd recommend making these two resistor strings identical:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFz3L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But you will have to take common mode noise into account.

Comment: @ Yeap ... it was inverted. The tools I have to work with are ... rudimentary at best. After a night of sleep I noticed that I might be connecting to live instead of neutral. I switched the plug today (literally turned it 180° and connected it again) and the 220V AC disappeared. My problem now is that there is a DC voltage  between the USB ground and my ground, which does not let me program mi microcontroller since it has 1V signals (measuring from the PCB gnd to the signal).        Also resistors r4, r5 and r6 are 200k and r7, r8, r9 are 820

Comment: I also connected a 60v capacitor from N to 0V, because my signal wasn't good enough and after that it got much better, a very pretty sine wave

Comment: @morcillo I don't get what you're doing with the 1Vdc GND-EARTH. That is normal. Also the capacitor I do not follow. You need to take a step away and draw up the full schematics of what you're hooking up before continuing.

Comment: I ended up removing it, so what I have is what you can see in the schematic I provided. And I meant to say 3V instead of one .. it was a typo. I'm afraid I won't be able to program my microcontroller because the JTAG signals will be different to what the microcontroller is seing and then not being able to load my firmware

Comment: I was hoping that this could have a simpler solution, but apparently I'll have to cut a lot of wires in my board in order to have a usable board. At the moment I wired up 5Vdc to my board and am now able to remove the 3Vdc GND-EARTH, so I think I'll be able to program my board (hopefully .. waiting for the new st link I bought). The way that it is now, I can connect my board to mains and get a pretty good AC signal for my ADC ... I was really hoping that I could fix this with just  few mods, but apparently a redesign is in order??

Comment: In my current circuit there is a short to earth ground when I connect the USB. Would that change (or get better) if I change the resistor values for  r7, r8 and r9? Maybe something in the vecinity of 100kOhms? Doesn't matter what happens, whenever I connect the USB the circuit breaker activates (controlled environment, I actually got a breaker just for my use). I can see that it is because of the short to ground, but would an isolation transformer really protect my circuit? Would I be able to program my board? It doesn't seem possible due to r7, r8 and r9

Comment: @morcillo Google for differential probes and how they work.

Comment: Ok. I'll mark this as answered. Sorry it took me such a long time but I wanted to be sure